# AWS Lambda Function is not executing in Simple Work Flow (SWF)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-swf

We are creating a Workflow which has multiple activities. One of the activity is directly invoking a Lambda Function. Lambda function executes properly with out the workflow (Using AWS Lambda Console). When its invoked using using SWF the function is not scheduled and does not throw any error.

Skeleton of Lambda function is given below.

```
public String handleRequest(String path, Context context) {
        System.out.println("unknown status");
        return "unknown status";
    }
```

Workflow implementation is

```
public class WorkflowAImpl implements WorkflowA {

    private ActivityOneClient processClient = new ActivityOneClientImpl();
    private ActivityTwoClient filterClient = new ActivityTwoClientImpl();

    @Override
    public Promise<String> process(String BucketNameFromMain,
            String Message) {
        WorkflowStatistics statistics = new WorkflowStatistics();
        DecisionContextProvider context = new DecisionContextProviderImpl();
        DecisionContext decisionContext = context.getDecisionContext();
        String workflowName = context.getDecisionContext().getWorkflowContext()
                .getWorkflowExecution().getWorkflowId();
        String workflowId = context.getDecisionContext().getWorkflowContext()
                .getWorkflowExecution().getRunId();
        BucketName = BucketNameFromMain;
        Promise<String> FirstDone = FirstActivity();
        Promise<String> SecondDone = translateMessageActivity(FirstDone,decisionContext);

        Promise<String> ThirdDone = insertMessageActivity(SecondDone);

        return ThirdDone;

    }

    @Asynchronous
    public Promise<String> FirstActivity() {
        Promise<String> FirstDone = processClient.ProcessMessage();
        return FirstDone;
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public Promise<String> insertMessageActivity(Promise<String> SecondDone) {
        Promise<String> ThirdDone = filterClient.FilterMessage();
        return ThirdDone;
    }

    @Asynchronous
    public Promise<String> translateMessageActivity(Promise<String> FirstDone,DecisionContext decisionContext) {
        LambdaFunctionClient lambdaClient =decisionContext.getLambdaFunctionClient();
        Promise<String> SecondDone =lambdaClient.scheduleLambdaFunction("LambdaFunctionName",inputData);
        return SecondDone;
    }



}
```

It is executing the first activity. After that its doesn't schedule the lambda function. Kindly Help

Ref : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/awsflowguide/lambda-task.html
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/tree/master/src/samples/AwsFlowFramework/src/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/examples/hellolambda

Comment: Are you sure that the IAM role associated with your workflow grants permission to call your Lambda function?

Comment: Yup I created a seperate role which have admin permission

Comment: Did you attach the role to the workflow? Also, in the aws console, whats the status of the workflow, is it in active or failed state? If it is failed then whats the error stack?